# Tracking time spent reading on a kindle?

Tags: kindle

Is there a way to track and export time spent reading on a Kindle?

I'm setting a goal around reading books several hours a week, and I would love to automate the tracking.

Amazon seems to track furthest page read and your bookmarks and highlights, but I can't find any way to track time spent. Ideally, I'd like to export this data as JSON or CSV.

Comment: Yes Kindle FreeTime is great for that purpose. I don't understand why Amazon has not changed its policy of targerting this feature to children only. I would also love to be able to add subscription magazines worth reading from cover to cover.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I discovered an answer to this in [this quora thread](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-ways-to-download-Kindle-reading-statistics):

> The only way I've found to do this is to get the latest firmware for the Kindle Paperwhite and enroll yourself in "Kindle FreeTime". This is a program intended to restrict the content that children can read while tracking their progress. It provides reading time, books read, pages read, etc. Why this is hidden behind a feature that is 100% directed at children is unclear to me. But if you don't mind occasionally entering a parental control password (I just set mine to a single letter) and jumping through a few hoops, I'd checkout FreeTime.

I verified the solution, and [wrote up a guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20180720171506/https://www.dshack.net/2014/11/04/tracking-reading-statistics-on-the-kindle/). Using Freetime, you can definitely track these metrics.

[image: freetime metrics]

Comment: Free time only works with purchased content

Comment: Guide site can't be reached at the moment