# Track Pages Per Day on Kindle

Tags: kindle

I was curious if I can track the pages read per day on a Kindle. The two options I've found have not been updated in years:

1) [This StackExchange answer utilizing Amazon's FreeTime](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/2536/tracking-time-spent-reading-on-a-kindle)

2) [This GitHub repo that involves jailbreaking a Kindle](https://github.com/mattbnz/kindle-utils) (which I am fine doing)

I was just curious if there is a more updated option.

Answer (score 2):

By "track the pages read per day" do you mean the pages *you* read? Or anyone reading a book you *wrote*?

If the latter, you can get the Kindle Normalized Page Read figure:

"The number of Kindle Edition Normalized Pages (KENP) read determines the royalties you earn from KU (Kindle Unlimited) and KOLL (Kindle Owners’ Lending Library). This graph is updated as pages are read by customers who borrow your book from KU and KOLL. Use the filters above to customize your data."